Level Set Theorem for general Manifolds
I want to understand the proof of the followign theorem:
Let $ f:M\to N$ a smooth map between manifolds. Let $q\in N$. Then $L = \{p\in f^{-1}(q) \mid f \ is \ submersive \ at \ p\}$ is either empty or a submanifold of dimension $m-n$ in $M$.
For the proof we use the following criterium. We know by an earlier result that $L$ is a submanifold iff for all $p\in L$ there is a chart $\sigma: U \to M$ ($U \subset R^m $ open) around $p$ s.t $\sigma(U)\cap N = \sigma(U\cap R^n)$.
So the proof goes as follows: Let $p \in L$. Then $f$ is submersive at $p$ hence by the Theorem about submersive maps (see Wikipedia Submersion) There are charts $\tau: U \to N$ and $\sigma:V\to M$ such that $\tau^{-1}f\sigma = \pi$  where $\pi$ is is the projection $R^m \to R^n$. Now comes the part I dont understand. My Lecture notes now claim the following. Obviously we have $\sigma(u) \in L$ if and only if $ \pi(u) =0$ if and only if $\sigma(U) \cap L = \sigma (U \cap R^{n-m})$ which proofs the claim by the local criterium. I dont get both if and only ifs and I have absolutely no idea where they come from.
Any idea?

I think you have confused the roles of $\sigma$ and $\tau$ in some places. For example, $\sigma(u)\in L$ does not parse ($\sigma$ takes values in $N$, $L$ lies in $M$).

@Thorgott yes thank you I swapped $\sigma$ and $\tau$ now everything should be right

You need one more detail about the charts, which is that $0\in U$ and $\tau(0)=q$ resp. $0\in V$ and $\sigma(0)=p$. First of all, $f$ is submersive at every point of $\sigma(U)$ (since $\pi$ is a submersion), so $\sigma(v)\in L$ if and only if $f\sigma(v)=q$ if and only if $\tau\pi(v)=q=\tau(0)$ if and only if $\pi(v)=0$ since $\tau$ is injective. Thus, $\sigma(U)\cap L=\sigma(\pi^{-1}(0))=\sigma(U\cap\mathbb{R}^{m-n})$.

where and how exactly do you use that $f$ is submersive at $\sigma(U)$?

@user1072285 The assumption is used to obtain the charts $\sigma$ and $\tau$, as you already argued in the question.
